# Yet another CSS layout puzzle

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to have a date picker and time picker from the start of a campaign and a similar pair for the end.

I would like to have them side by side with the date pickers above the time pickers, thus:

```
-------------------------  
| ---------  ---------  |  
| | start  | | end    | |   
| | date   | | date   | |  
| | picker | | picker | |  
| ----------  --------- |  
| ---------   --------  |  
| | start  | | end    | |  
| | time   | | time   | |  
| | picker | | picker | |  
| ----------  --------- |  
-------------------------
```

I have tried this

```
<div>
   <span>
       <datepicker ng-model="campaignStartDate" datepicker-options="datePickerOptions"></datepicker>

       <timepicker ng-model="campaignStartTime" show-meridian=true></timepicker>                            
   </span>

    <span>
         <datepicker ng-model="campaignEndDate" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true"></datepicker>

          <timepicker ng-model="campaignEndTime" show-meridian=true></timepicker>                            
     </span>
</div>
```

but it is not displaying as I want - what am I doing wrong?

---

I realize., as as I stated in a comment below, that it is time for me to re-hone my CSS skills. This time last year, I would not have asked sucha question.

For anyone else interested in a CSS based grid system, there are several generators online, and [a great description of CSS grids](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) from W3C. You may need to read it a few times, but it explains all that you need to now.

Hint: CSS3 actually supports grids. Take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-rows-columns/), [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [this](http://gridbyexample.com/examples/), etc, etc, etc.

Comment: So, where is the CSS?

Comment: Lolx - there isn't any - that's whee I am stuck. How do I use CSS styles to align the date & time pickers as I want?

Comment: What have you tried so far in using CSS to fix this issue? A simple "how do I use CSS" is too broad of a question.

Comment: Alas, I do not know where to start. As far as I can see, the HTML structure should do what I want, and I do not understand why not

Comment: You don't need any css to accomplish a very rudimentary layout like that.  You could use a `<table>`, or perhaps change your `<span>`s to `<div>`s.

Comment: I thought that tables were frowned upon? If changing spans to divs is the answer, please post that.

Comment: There are plenty of options out there: float and flexbox would be ideal candidates. However you can't expect us to write code for you—take some time and invest some effort in learning CSS. Your layout can be easily achieved by just googling, anyway.

Comment: Points well made, Terry. I am just rusty, having been away from web-based stuff for a while (busy with embedded). In this case, my problem was caused by the Angular date picker having a width of 450+ pixels of which only 300 are visible, so I could not understand the wrapping. Yup, time to resharpen the old CSS skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of one way to show elements side-by-side:

```css
.boxes,
.boxes div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.boxes div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```